# База данных MSSQL без установки сервера MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Раньше, чтобы использовать базу данных MSSQL на другом компьютере, приходится устанавливать сервер баз данных MSSQL.
А сегодня как дела обстоят с этим? Теперь то же самое, или уже можно брать базу данных на другой компьютер, не устанавливая в обязательном порядке сервер?

Comment: да, нужно установить mssql на другой машине. Но можно просто использовать sqlite и тогда сервер не нужен будет.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток. В этом случае вам поможет MS SQL Compact Edition... Базу можно использовать без наличия самого MS SQL. Ну и копировать и работать. Правда это накладывает определенные ограничения и на программу и на маштабируемость решения. А существует данное решение очень давно и вроде как создавалось для мобильных систем еще в пору  PocketPC.

Comment: В данной ситуации не так важна масштабируемость, а в моей работе хватит где-то 1000 строк, если не больше.

Comment: Смотрел MS SQL Compact Edition. Вроде то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

Уточните, что значит "брать базу  на другом компьютере", чтобы писать запросы к БД на каком нибудь сервере вам нужна ms sql management studio она ставиться вместе с sql сервером. Вы можете поставить к себе на компьютер ms sql server express и подключиться к базам которые работают на сервере, но лучше уточните вопрос.

Comment: Извини, если нечетко сформулировав вопрос.
Допустим, я создам базу данных с 4 таблицами в ms sql server, и написав программу CRUD с данными этой базы данных.
Вот скопирую программу с этой базой данных со своего компьютера на другой, на котором нет ms sql server.

Comment: ни разу не видел, чтобы c базами созданных в  MSSQL SERVER, можно было работать автономно,  без самой СУБД.

Comment: Вот я и спросил. Может, что-то новое ввели в MS SQL?